# Using Node Parse API for self-hosted Parse Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, parse-platform, configuration

I finished building a Parse Server on Parse Platform. In my old Parse App, I utilize this REST API library for NodeJS

How should I configure (in Parse initialization or Parse library module) to send REST request to this newly built Parse Server. For example, configuration of my Parse Server contains:

```
﻿{
"appId": my_app_id,
"masterKey": my_master_key,
"port": "1337",
"serverURL": my_server_url,
"publicServerURL": my_server_url,
"mountPath": "/parse",
"databaseURI": my_database_uri"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node module is specify the serverUrl to api.parse.com, and origin mount path is '1'.
https://github.com/Leveton/node-parse-api/blob/master/lib/Parse.js

Try these 2 step. 
1. set Parse._api_host to your host. 2. change your mountPath to '1'.

Another Parse Rest API util is kaiseki, there is a pr to fit open source parse  but not been merged.
https://github.com/shiki/kaiseki/pull/35

Comment: Thanks very much. kaiseki helps me much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request module and do something like this:

```
request({
                url: 'my_server_url',
                //qs: {foo:  bar}, //these are the query string if you want to use them
                method: 'POST', //you get the REST options here
                json: {
                    foo2:   bar1,
                    foo3: bar2
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, I want to utilize the already built API
https://github.com/Leveton/node-parse-api